# Dissect text file using delimiters piece by piece

Tags: xcode, file-io, csv

I have a file that contains a bunch of info which is separated by delimiters. So my delimiters (in the plain text file) look something like this:

```
<start>   
//some of info
<end>
```

How can I read in text, piece by piece, based on certain delimiters I'm looking for?
Also, is it possible to read upto a certain point in the file, and pause there, so next time i access the data, I start looking from the previously stopped point?

Comment: Currently it only has about a paragraph of text, but in the future i plan on it having a lot of pages of data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file is small enough to fit into memory (say 5MB or less), you can read the file into an `NSString` using the `stringWithContentsOfFile` method, and then parse the string with an `NSScanner`. The `NSScanner` will keep track of the current location in the string, which you can query using `scanLocation`.  You can also modify the scan location with the `setScanLocation` method. Here's some sample to code to help you get started with `NSScanner`.  The code just looks for tags in the input, and uses an `NSLog` to print out any tags it finds.

```
- (void)scandemo
{
    NSString *input = @"<start>\n//some of info\n<end>";
    NSString *tagName;

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];
    for (;;)
    {
        // find the opening bracket
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL];

        if ( [scanner isAtEnd] )
            break;

        // swallow the < character
        if ( ![scanner scanString:@"<" intoString:NULL] )
            break;

        // find the closing bracket, and print out the tag
        if ( [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&tagName] )
            NSLog( @"found tag <%@>", tagName );

        if ( [scanner isAtEnd] )
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NSScanner you can also use a method of the NSString class called contentsSeparatedByString. This returns an array. Here's a full example:

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-read-the-contents-from-a-text-file-into-an-nsstring/